# What is the equivalent of numpy.allclose for structured numpy arrays?

Tags: numpy

Running `numpy.allclose(a, b)` throws `TypeError: invalid type promotion` on structured arrays. What would be the correct way of checking whether the contents of two structured arrays are almost equal?

Comment: Please tell us the full dtypes of the arrays involved.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution which works for arbitrary structured arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`np.allclose` does an `np.isclose` followed by `all()`.  `isclose` tests `abs(x-y)` against tolerances, with accomodations for `np.nan` and `np.inf`.  So it is designed primarily to work with floats, and by extension ints.

The arrays have to work with `np.isfinite(a)`, as well as `a-b` and `np.abs`.  In short `a.astype(float)` should work with your arrays.

None of this works with the compound dtype of a structured array.  You could though iterate over the fields of the array, and compare those with `isclose` (or `allclose`).  But you will have ensure that the 2 arrays have matching `dtypes`, and use some other test on fields that don't work with `isclose` (eg. string fields).

So in the simple case

```
all([np.allclose(a[name], b[name]) for name in a.dtype.names])
```

should work.

If the fields of the arrays are all the same numeric dtype, you could view the arrays as 2d arrays, and do `allclose` on those.  But usually structured arrays are used when the fields are a mix of string, int and float.  And in the most general case, there are compound dtypes within dtypes, requiring some sort of recursive testing.

```
import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rf
```

has functions to help with complex structured array operations.

Comment: a.dtype.names gives me None on "O" dtype

Comment: @DanielMalachov, what were you expecting?  `dtype.names` is only useful when used with a `structured array`, one with a `compound dtype`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `b` is a scalar, you can just iterate over the fields of `a`:

```
all(np.allclose(a[field], b) for field in a.dtype.names)
```